# Rails: ArgumentError - you can't define an already defined column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, has-many-through

I have a Rails 6 app (6.0.0rc1). It has book and author models that have has_many :through associations. I created a join table with

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableAuthorsBook author:references books:references
```

As you can see, I named the table incorrectly and I referenced the book incorrectly. I deleted the migration and created a new migration

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableAuthorsBooks author:references book:references
```

Now when I run the migration, I get

```
ArgumentError: you can't define an already defined column 'author_id'.
```

I've searched my entire Rails app, but I can't find 'author_id' anywhere. I ran the previous migration (the one with the incorrect values). How can I delete the previous 'author_id' so I can successfully run the migration?

Comment: Did you already run `db:migrate` with the previous migration?

Comment: Yes, I ran the previous migration.

Answer (score 5):

***UPDATE*** The problem likely lies in the new migration. In Rails 5.2 (I don't have Rails 6 handy) `rails g migration CreateJoinTableAuthorsBooks author:references book:references` produces a migration like so:

```
create_join_table :authors, :books do |t|
  t.references :author, foreign_key: true
  t.references :book, foreign_key: true
end
```

`create_join_table :authors, :books` already creates a table with references (although they're not declared foreign keys). `t.references :author` and `t.references :book` are redundant. In Rails 5.2 this redundancy is overlooked, but perhaps Rails 6 does not.

For this reason I'd recommend tweaking your migration so everything is properly declared and indexed.

```
create_join_table :authors, :books, column_options: { null: false, foreign_key: true } do |t|
  t.index [:author_id, :book_id]
  t.index [:book_id, :author_id]
end
```

---

The normal procedure for fixing a goofed migration is to first rollback the migration with `rails db:rollback`, *then* delete the bad migration file. Rolling back requires the migration you're rolling back still exists (and is reversible).

Otherwise, start with a fresh development database using the version in `db/schema.rb` with `rails db:reset`. Note this will blow away your dev and test databases; that shouldn't be an issue. Be sure your `db/schema.rb` doesn't contain changes from your goofed migration, usually you can assure this by checking it out from version control.

Finally if everything is really messed up including `db/schema.rb`, `rails db:migrate:reset` will re-run all your migrations, rebuild `db/schema.rb` fresh, and provide you with fresh development and test databases.

Comment: When I run `rails db:migrate:reset`, I get the same error. If I run `rails db:reset`, I get `You have 1 pending migration: CreateJoinTableAuthorsBooks`.

Comment: @hashrocket `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Comment: @engineersmnky: I've tried that. Still get the same error.

Comment: @hashrocket Are you ***sure*** you deleted that bad migration file? If so, could you show us the content of the new migration?

Comment: @hashrocket Is it possible that `author:references book:references` is redundant with `create_join_table`? Should that be `rails g migration CreateJoinTableAuthorsBooks author book`?

Comment: Here’s what I’ve done. I created a new empty migration named `CreateJoinTableAuthorsBooks`. I ran `rails db:migrate`. Then I added in `author:references and book:references`. I did a quick test and it seems to have worked. I had to leave, so I’ll do more tests tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

```
create_join_table :authors, :books
```

will fix it for you as rails 6 doesn't need those declarations.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when working on a Rails 6 application.

```
== 20200711132707 CreateProducts: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:products)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

you can't define an already defined column 'voltage'.
```

**Here’s how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I defined a model attribute twice, which in this case was `voltage:decimal`. So when I run `rails db:migrate` it throws the error.

I fixed by first **deleting the migration file** for products.

And then **recreating the migration** for products.

This time when I ran `rails db:migrate` everything worked well.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
you do NOT need anymore the references:

```
# remove these:
t.references :author, foreign_key: true
t.references :book, foreign_key: true
```

**Note**: you can still use the options used in `t.references` with `create_join_table`, using the `column_options` arg.

For example:

```
create_join_table :authors, :books, column_options: { type: :uuid, null: false, index: true, foreign_key: true } do |t|
    ...
end
```